# Batch-Script for copying and overwritting existing files

Tags: batch, batch-file

So I've got a file called modified.txt, however the same file is in a bazillion folders and subfolders.

I want to copy the modified.txt to all these bazillion folders and subfolders and overwritte the existing modified.txt files.

Say I have it all in

D:\txt\folder 1

-- D:\txt\subfolder 1

D:\txt\folder 2

D:\txt\folder 3

How do I go about that with a batch scrip, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the new "modified.txt" file is in a different location, call it "d:\new\modified.txt", then the following will work on the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "d:\txt\modified.txt"') do copy "d:\new\modified.txt" "%%~dpF"
```

Double the percents if you use it in a batch script.

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Now if I may bother you a bit further. Assuming "d:\txt" is where all the files are I want to overwrite. I edit all the files in d:\new and then drop each file to the run.bat . The file might be named "testcase.txt" or "whatareyoudoing.txt" etc, but they are all also present in d:\txt and its subfolders. So, how do I go about that without constantly editing the run.bat file?

Comment: @DonSalva - Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. It sounds like a new question anyway.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to Use find to find all files named modified.txt
then for each file found copy your new file over writing the found file.

Comment: Exactly the opposite of what I want. Copying for each file is what I want to do with the batch script. I'm not going to manually copy over bazillion files.

Comment: I didn't suggest do it manually, I said use find. eg find d:\txt -name modified.txt -exec cp -v /new/modified.txt {} \;